# Can I put 'about' in "I'll email you 'about' the date"

Tags: prepositions

When the date of the party is fixed, I'll let you know.  In this situation, should I say:

> I'll email you the date.

or can I say:

> I'll email you about the date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference between the two.

> I'll email you the date

means that I will have or know the day and time of some event or observation, and I will share it by email with someone. (Here, *date* is the direct object of *email*, and *you* is the indirect object.)

> I'll email about the date

means that I will email for some purpose relating to the date; there is no explicit object. Perhaps the purpose is to tell you what it is, as in the first case, but perhaps it is to initiate a conversation about it.

Thus, while the second can often substitute for the first, the reverse is not true. If I am inviting you to one of two baseball games playing next Wednesday or Thursday, and you are not sure when you are available, for me to say *I'll email about the date* is to say that we will need to continue the conversation over email once you have more information. To say *I'll email the date* is to say am no longer giving you the option to choose which day's game you will attend.

Comment: I like how you explained how one might be substituted for the other, but that can only be done one way.